# Find the number of occurrence of each character in a string In C

Tags: c

I have a problem in C where i have to find number of occurrence of each character in a string.Suppose i have string like "amitamt" and output should be like "a2m2it2" .I have a routine from which i can find no of occurrence of a particular character.

```
int count_chars(const char* string, char ch)
{
int count = 0;
int i;

int length = strlen(string);

for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (string[i] == ch)
    {
        count++;
    }
}


return count;
}
```

But I am not sure how could I count each character of string

Comment: No not exactly Home work

Answer (score 4):

If you have an ASCII string, create an int array of size 256. Then loop through the string and increment the value in the int array on position x. While x is the ASCII value of the character in your string you're looping through.

Comment: If you have an ASCII string, 128 is fine.

Comment: Well, it's actually 100, if you nit pick :p, but the you have more overhead because you have to calculate index and use `if` more often..

Comment: @duedl0r: Where do you get 100?  There are 128 [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) characters, including control characters.

Comment: Unless the string length is limited by INT_MAX (maximum int value) or UINT_MAX (maximum unsigned int value), it should be an array of size_t's. And there should be UCHAR_MAX elements in it if you want to allow for all possible char values (reason: there may be more than 8 bits in a char) and individual chars should be cast to unsigned char before being used as indices into the array (rationale: chars can be signed or unsigned, which is implementation-specific). Also, obviously, the array should be zeroed before incrementing its elements.

Comment: You should use this solution unless the amount of RAM of the system is very limited, this is the fastest possible way.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm not sure it's the fastest way, due to how serial the loop is on memory.  Since the function is a monoid homomorphism, there might be a way to speed it up.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, depending on what you use.. you can also use 8bit ascii code.. since I'm not american I use 8bit :) The number 100 is coming from a random definition.. depending on what you have to count.. not really relevant. For example, only count the printable characters, or only [a-zA-Z]...

Comment: @duedl0r: ASCII has 128 characters, by definition; 8-bit character sets are not ASCII.

Comment: @KeithThompson: You're right. But there are extended ascii characters: http://www.asciitable.com/ do they have a different name?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: how can you speed things up using the monoid homomorphism property?

Comment: @duedl0r: Err, actually I'd use the fact that the function is a monoid homomorphism to a commutative monoid.  Simply compute N histograms simultaneously, each for the elements in the array with a different residue modulo N.  At the end, sum histograms.  I'm optimistic of a speedup of 10%-50% or so.

Comment: In closer-to-layman's terms: the problem is what we call "embarrassingly parallel".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: You can make a parallel algorithm for the same reason.  But to be clear, the technique I described does not use parallelism.

Comment: How are you planning to compute anything simultaneously without parallelism? Or are you just talking about manually unrolling the loop?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I'm also very interested in your technique..could you describe that a bit more? I don't get it..

Comment: @duedl0r: Yes, there are a number of different names: Latin-1, Windows-1252, etc.  They're based on ASCII (generally supersets of it), but they're not ASCII.

Comment: @duedl0r: Something like this: `unsigned *p, h[256][4], i, len; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {  h[p[i]>>24][0]++; h[(p[i]>>16)&255][1]++; h[(p[i]>>8)&255][2]++; h[p[i]&255][3]++; }`

Answer (score 1):

if i have any mistakes like syntax please excuse as im working on vb , Im unable to figure out where to put braces or brackets ,

and I belive strchr makes your task easier

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int str_occ (char *pch ,char a)
 {
   int  i = 0;
   char *p;
   p=strchr(pch,a);
   while (p!=NULL)
   {
     i = i+1;
     p = strchr(p+1,a);
   }
   return i;
 }
```

To explain the code *pch is the string you have to pass ,char a is the alphabet you are searching to find how many times its occurring and int i returns the value of number of occurrences

say sample

```
 int main()  
{
  char a[]="hello world";
  int i;
  i=str_occ(a,'l');
  printf("%d",i);
}
 output is 3
```

You can make the code as per your requirements, keep caling the function inside a loop , I mean rotate your elements

Comment: Some code comments: In the first example, you forgot to initialize i. The loop should search from `strchr(p+1, a)` or it will loop forever. In the 3rd example, don't call strlen from the inside the loop. Also, this algorithm is terribly inefficient as you loop the same string several times, and it will count the same kind of character several times if it occurs more than once.

Comment: Lundin I aprreciate your comments I just wanted to guide the way to him , and sorry if i misguide him Thanks !

Comment: well I did not give him the entire solution just helped him the way to approach !

Comment: I do appreciate your help @Niko.